# Google Search api for Android systems

Tags: android, google-search-api

I'm trying to build an android app that would do a local search on google.

I know there is a [Google Search API for Java](http://code.google.com/p/gsearch-java-client/), and I am able to use it for a desktop application. However, when I use the same jar file (gsearch.jar) in my android project, Some problems arise.

When I call the .localSearch() method of my gsearch.Client object, a runtime error is occurring. The error message is: "java.lang.VerifyError: gsearch.Client". This message is occurring in the Dalvik Debug Monitor log.

So what is the problem here? Can I not use the search API on the android?

More importantly, how do I do a local search from an android app? Does the android sdk have search APIs inbuilt? I could only find the Maps api, and Map search is not what I'm looking for..

Thanks for the help,

jrh

Comment: means the search you do on "local.google.com"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg76067.html) a solution using a JSON call to google [ajax local search](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_fonje_local) without using java gsearch library.

Comment: and how about a "local search" on google? like on local.google.com?