# Any examples of a custom google API search in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android , I want help with Google custom search API use in Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499324/google-search-api-for-android-systems

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get helpful answers to your question, you need to be a little more specific. Please edit your answer to include a short description of what exactly you want to achieve, what you tried so far and/or where you got stuck in your way there.