# Google Search feature inside an application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to embed Google Search inside my application. How can I make approach for this?
Is there any .jar file or any package is there which will support Google Search within an application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499324/google-search-api-for-android-systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use json. you need to api key signup.

this page will help you.

http://code.google.com/intl/ko-KR/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html

previous one in comment is depricated.